# Umbraco - Displaying a specific image within a macro for-each child of certain node

Tags: macros, umbraco

Umbraco newbie here. I've researched a tonne but can't seem to find what I' looking for.

I have a site with a slider on the homepage, the slider is sitting in a macro which is using a for-each (of a nodes children) with a final goal to display the 'heroImage' image from that doctype. I cant post images as a newbie to this site, but heres my content structure:

```
HOME
PORTFOLIO
 - First Item
 - Another Item
ABOUT
CONTACT US
```

**Home, Portfolio, ABOUT** and **CONTACT US** are *"Landing Pages" document types*, and the children under Portfolio (**First Item** and **Another Item**) are *"Portfolio Entries" document types*. Below is the code on *"Landing Page"* calling the Slideshow macro.

Portfolio Entry has fields:

- heroImage
- images
- body

Slideshow macro obviously being the highlight there. Easy enough. Heres my macro code where you'll see I'm trying to display the heroImage of the node in question for each 'for-each'.

```
<xsl:template match="/">

    <!-- slider -->
    <div id="slideshow">
        <div id="slider" class="nivoSlider">
            <xsl:for-each select="umbraco.library:GetXmlNodeById(1081)/*[@isDoc and position() &lt; 4]">
                <xsl:variable name="mediaId" select="umbraco.library:GetMedia(@id, 'false')/data [@alias = 'umbracoFile']" />
                <xsl:if test="$mediaId &gt; 0">
                    <xsl:variable name="mediaNode" select="umbraco.library:GetMedia($mediaId, 0)" />
                    <xsl:if test="count($mediaNode/data) &gt; 0 and string($mediaNode/data[@alias='umbracoFile']) != ''">
                        <img src="{$mediaNode/data[@alias='umbracoFile']}" alt="[image]" />
                    </xsl:if>
                </xsl:if>
            </xsl:for-each>
        </div>
    </div>
    <!-- data-transition="slideInLeft" -->
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(window).load(function() {
        $('#slider').nivoSlider();
        });
    </script>

</xsl:template>
```

I feel like im so close, and ran out of search queries as most of the solutions I found were dependant on the imageId being passed onto the macro from the other side of the macro which wouldn't work.

Hope Ive explained this enough and thanks in advance for your help!

Answer (score 0):

First of all, it looks like you're hardcoding the parent node id. In the code you just provided, it seems to **only** be getting the children of the node with id 1081. From reading what you just posted, it would seem that on all landing pages, you want to display their individual portfolio entries.

Either way, I would stay away from hardcoding IDs. If the node id changes in any way(user deletes the node, it gets exported as a package to the live environment, etc), your code will stop working. I'd just use $currentPage instead.

Judging by your filter, I imagine you only want the first 3 items to show in the slider. The code seems correct, **but** you seem to be using the old schema and its associated xpath. If you're using a newer version of Umbraco, the way you reference node data in xslt would have changed. I would guess that you've found many code examples and tried merging them together, without realising they wouldn't call the same schema.

[This wiki link](http://our.umbraco.org/wiki/reference/xslt/45-xml-schema/xslt-examples-updated-to-new-schema) will provide more information, and hopefully fix your problem if you're using the wrong xpath.